# How can I draw specific edge's color according to its node in networkx?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, social-networking

I'm new to Python.
I have a Louvain clustered graph, and I want the edge's colour of the graph following its node's color.
Here is my code:

```py
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import matplotlib.cm as cm
  import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
  import numpy as np
  partition_louvain = community.best_partition(G)
  size = float(len(set(partition_louvain.values())))
  pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
  count = 0.
  communities_louvain = []
  cmap=mymap
  #cmap = cm.get_cmap("BlueRedGreen")
  for com in set(partition_louvain.values()):
      count = count + 1.
      list_nodes = [nodes for nodes in partition_louvain.keys()
                    if partition_louvain[nodes] == com]
      communities_louvain.append(list_nodes)
      nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, list_nodes, node_size=20,connectionstyle='arc3',
                            node_color=cmap(count / size))
  #'''
  cmap2 = cm.get_cmap("jet")
  #norm = plt.Normalize(pos[e[0]].min(), pos[e[0]].max())
  ax = plt.gca()
  for e in G.edges:
      norm = plt.Normalize(pos[e[0]].min(), pos[e[0]].max())
      cmap2 = cm.get_cmap("jet")
      ax.annotate("",
              xy=pos[e[0]], xycoords='data',  
              xytext=pos[e[1]], textcoords='data',
              arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color=cmap2(norm(pos[e[0]])),
                              shrinkA=5, shrinkB=5,
                              patchA=None, patchB=None,
                              connectionstyle="arc3,rad=rrr".replace('rrr',str(0.3*e[2])

                              ),
                              ),
              )
  plt.show()
```

I only can plot the arrow into a single colour, by changing colour argument into something like

> `color='blue'.`

Comment: Is there a reason, why you not use [`draw_networkx_edges`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html)? Because else your question is rather a `matplotlib` question than a `networkx` question.

Comment: @Sparky05 yes, because i want to use multiple edge and using connectionstyle=arc3 to my edge, im sorry.ive tried using draw_networkx_edges with arc3 but its not working. is there a way to use draw_networkx_edges and also using arc3?

Comment: Then could you add the `matplotlib` tag and create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with all the required imports and only the necessary parts (i.e. for the problem the clustering is not needed)

Comment: thank @Sparky05 i will edit my post